# iOS: AutoresizingMask using an array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, autoresizingmask

Is it possible to provide an array to the autoresizingMask property of UIView?  The reason I want to do this is that I have some conditions which determine which autoresizingMask properties I want to add to my my view.

So, instead of just using:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

I want to do something like:

```
if (addMargin) {
   [items addObject:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
}
if (addWidth) {
   [items addObject:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
}

// Add to property
self.view.autoresizingMask = items;
```

So I basically want to conditionally set the items of this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit mask. Just bitwise-OR it with the one you want.

```
if(addMargin)
    self.view.autoresizingMask |= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
if(addWidth)
    self.view.autoresizingMask |= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

To reset the mask, you can set it to 0, or if you want to remove a particular attribute you can negate it and bitwise-AND the mask with it:

```
if(removeMargin)
    self.view.autoresizingMask &= ~UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Answer (score 2):

Autoresizing is just a bit mask.

```
UIViewAutoresizing resize = 0;
if (addMargin) {
    resize = resize | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}
if (addWidth) {
    resize = resize | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
}

self.view.autoresizingMask = resize
```